# I was solving this problem - "Transform to sum tree". I have written it's code but it is showing an error

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

In this question, we have to convert all nodes of tree to the sum of it's child node and itself.
All, the things are right but it is showing an error of "Cannot read field "data" because "root.left" is null."
[This is image of error which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmSLc.png)

Here is full code -

```
public class BinaryTree09 {
    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }

    public static int transform(Node root){
        if(root == null){
            return 0;
        }
        int leftChild = transform(root.left);
        int rightChild = transform(root.right);
        
        int data = root.data;
        root.data = root.left.data + leftChild + root.right.data + rightChild;

        return data;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**   1
            /   \
           2     3
          / \   / \ 
         4   5 6   7
        */

        /*Expected Output
                 27
                /  \
               9    13
              / \   / \
             0   0 0   0
         */
       Node root = new Node(1);
       root.left = new Node(2);
       root.right = new Node(3);
       root.left.left = new Node(4);
       root.left.right = new Node(5);
       root.right.left = new Node(6);
       root.right.right = new Node(7);
       System.out.println(transform(root));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nishant, have you read my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a minor logical error. Specifically in this line:

```java
root.data = root.left.data + leftChild + root.right.data + rightChild;
```

By adding root.left.data and root.right.data you are doubling the value, and you are at risk of trying to access the data property of root.left and root.right when they could be null (which in fact is causing the error). The solution is to remove these two terms:

```java
root.data = leftChild + rightChild;
```

I also believe you should be returning `root.data` not the `data` variable which stores the original value. This is a simple fix to the return statement, making it:

```java
return root.data;
```

After removing the now redundant `data` variable, the new function is:

```java
public static int transform(Node root){
    if(root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int leftChild = transform(root.left);
    int rightChild = transform(root.right);
        
    root.data = root.left.data + leftChild + root.right.data + rightChild;

    return root.data;
}
```

Alternatively, the function does not need to be static (and really shouldn't be), after a couple minor tweaks your new solution would look like:

```java
public class BinaryTree09 {
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }

        public int transform() {
            int leftChild = this.left == null ? 0 : transform(this.left);
            int rightChild = this.right == null ? 0 : transform(this.right);
     
            this.data = leftChild + rightChild;

            return this.data;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Node root = new Node(1);
       root.left = new Node(2);
       root.right = new Node(3);
       root.left.left = new Node(4);
       root.left.right = new Node(5);
       root.right.left = new Node(6);
       root.right.right = new Node(7);
       System.out.println(root.transform());
    }
}
```